# How can I redirect unauthorized users to a login page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC5 and AD authorization. I want to redirect to a login page if there is no authorization. So I added some setting in web.config as below.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

But after it. When I start to debug. the homepage's URL is like below.

What's wrong with it? it seems returnUrl is the problem. any suggestions to fix it?

```
http://localhost:62435/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%...................
```

---

2019/08/05

I've solved my problem by setting the steps below.

1. change the web.config's setting.

From

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

To

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

2. add code as below.

> ```
> public class FilterConfig
>     {
>         public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
>         {
>             filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
>             // I've add code here
>             filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
>         }
>     }
> ```

By the way, I'm using UseCookieAuthentication.
I don't understand FormsAuthentication. and the difference between CookieAuthentication and FormsAuthentication.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Login action on the Account controller is secured, maybe with the `Authorize` attribute. Unauthenticated users need to be able to access Login so use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute with it.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()
    ...
```

Also, you said you're using MVC but your web.config Forms Authentication refers to login.aspx. Based on this - I think it just needs to be `~/Account/Login`